# Where is the local bin path of my stack executables

Tags: haskell-stack

I would to know where my executables are located when I'm building a Haskell Stack project on MacOS ?

These executables doesn't seem to update for some reasons... I would like to be sure they don't exist anymore by deleting them but no way to find where they are....

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here : https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#path

```
michael@d30748af6d3d:~/wai$ stack path
global-stack-root: /home/michael/.stack
stack-root: /home/michael/.stack
project-root: /home/michael/wai
config-location: /home/michael/wai/stack.yaml
bin-path: /home/michael/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-2.17/7.8.4/bin:/home/michael/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.8.4/bin:/home/michael/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.10.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
programs: /home/michael/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux
compiler: /home/michael/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.8.4/bin/ghc
compiler-bin: /home/michael/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.8.4/bin
local-bin-path: /home/michael/.local/bin
extra-include-dirs:
extra-library-dirs:
snapshot-pkg-db: /home/michael/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-2.17/7.8.4/pkgdb
local-pkg-db: /home/michael/wai/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-2.17/7.8.4/pkgdb
global-pkg-db: /home/michael/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.8.4/lib/ghc-7.8.4/package.conf.d
ghc-package-path: /home/michael/wai/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-2.17/7.8.4/pkgdb:/home/michael/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-2.17/7.8.4/pkgdb:/home/michael/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.8.4/lib/ghc-7.8.4/package.conf.d
snapshot-install-root: /home/michael/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-2.17/7.8.4
local-install-root: /home/michael/wai/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-2.17/7.8.4
snapshot-doc-root: /home/michael/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-2.17/7.8.4/doc
local-doc-root: /home/michael/wai/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-2.17/7.8.4/doc
dist-dir: .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.18.1.5
local-hpc-root: /home/michael/wai/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-2.17/7.8.4/hpc
```